# what is the purpose of 'js' folder inside magento root folder?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I had seen 'js' folders inside my different theme folders, but what is the purpose of 'js' folder inside the root directory of magento ?

[image]

while navigating through the folder i found an index file inside it. curiosly When i just entered the url in my browser :

```
localhost/gk/js
```

i got this output in my browser

```
SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js
```

this string is also visible in my live store, does this string provide any clues to hackers? im not a magento expert, Expecting more advises from experts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `js` folder contain js files that don't depend on the theme you are working on.
You will find here the prototype framework, some form validation files, some backend general files and other.

The other files that are theme dependend should be placed in `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}`.

And you don't need to worry about the message you see

```
 SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js
```

This is generated by the first lines of the `js/index.php` file

```
if (empty($_GET['f'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js";
    exit;
}
```

The `index.php` file from this folder, allows you to merge some js files when requested from the server for speed purposes.

Comment: i was little bit worried about "SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js"; Output.Thanks for ur answer !! <3

Comment: when the `/js/index.php` is actually used ?